# Javascript passing values from external functions to internal functions

Tags: javascript, function

I have three javascript functions. 
The main function is within script tags in my index.html file. 
I have two other functions that are in an external file named cities.js.

Beneath is the main function found within the script tags:

```
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 12,
center: coords,
mapTypeId: 'terrain'
}
```

This is for the Google Maps API.

The next two functions hold the coordinates for the map.

```
function ldn() {
    var coords = var coords = {lat: 51.509865, lng: -0.118092};

}
function birm() {
    var coords = {lat: 52.509865, lng: -0.2};
}
```

Essentially, I have a drop down box and when either 'ldn' or 'birm' is clicked, the functions in the external file are executed depending on which one is clicked.

I wish to take the coordinates within the functions and include them into the main function for the 'center' variable.

I hope this makes sense! I have tried calling the function in center (center: birm()) but it does not work as intended. Simply returning the coords doesn't work either.

Comment: could you please add complete code ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra that essentially is it, I have left the styling out of the main function as I know its not that

Comment: You can call the `initMap()` function inside the `ldn` or `birm` function with passing the argument cords

Comment: I don't know where you have embed external js, but should be above the main function.

Comment: @Sovary I have it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the Map object with the click of a button and it doesn't have a method to do so, you have to recreate it.

With the code below the map gets initialised to the new position using your functions:

```js
var defaultCoords = {
  lat: 52.509865,
  lng: -0.2
}

function initMap(coords) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: coords || defaultCoords,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
}

function ldn() {
  var coords = {
    lat: 51.509865,
    lng: -0.118092
  };
  initMap(coords);
}

function birm() {
  var coords = {
    lat: 52.509865,
    lng: -0.2
  };
  initMap(coords);
}
```

But if there is a method to apply new coordinates (`.setCenter()`) to the map you have to store the object outside of `initMap()`:

```js
var defaultCoords = {
  lat: 52.509865,
  lng: -0.2
}
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: defaultCoords,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
}

function ldn() {
  var coords = {
    lat: 51.509865,
    lng: -0.118092
  };
  map.setCenter(coords);
}

function birm() {
  var coords = {
    lat: 52.509865,
    lng: -0.2
  };
  map.setCenter(coords);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I keep getting this error though - Uncaught ReferenceError: coords is not defined

Comment: I just fixed an error in my code. There were wrong variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The `initMap` is only run once to initialize the map.

If you want to recenter it later based on your choices use

```
function ldn() {
    var coords = {lat: 51.509865, lng: -0.118092};
    map.setCenter(coords);

}
function birm() {
    var coords = {lat: 52.509865, lng: -0.2};
    map.setCenter(coords);
}
```

This assumes that the `map` variable is global.